# How to know what is trashing my Linux mint system?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, troubleshooting, memory-leaks

My linux system is trashing occassionally. I have 4 GB of ram which is good even for Windows 8. All in all I have good specs. But occasionally the HDD light in the CPU is on for a long time and at the same time the system is not responding. I can't even kill processes. The whole system is hanging.

I want to know what is causing this.

---

As requested:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
60
```

Comment: `iotop` can tell you which processes are accessing your hard drive.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Does it keep a log of it. Because I'm unable to do anything when the system is trashing

Comment: Not by default. But I expect you could configure it to do so. Or use a similar tool.

Comment: See e.g. http://articles.slicehost.com/2010/11/12/using-iotop-to-check-i-o-and-swap .With `-b` it runs in batch mode.

Comment: What makes you think it is a memory leak? If so, why haven't you bothered to explain your swap setup?

Comment: When you say you can't even kill processes, does that mean that "kill -9 pid" returns but does not actually result in the process exiting, or just that you can't raise a terminal window to type in the kill command?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick The mouse and keyboard is not being processed. I can't even input using Keyboard or mouse. Even the mouse pointer doesn't move.

Comment: Hi Ufoguy. Does the machine eventually give back control after one of these episodes? In any case, have you tried running `iotop` in batch mode?

Comment: @FaheemMitha No, I just reset it! I'll try that but I'm unable to understand the instructions.

Comment: Ufoguy, the instructions just tell you how to set up a cron job, and even tell you what to write, though it may require adjustment depending on your distribution. Also take a look at the comments - the suggestion to use `logger` sounds reasonable. If you can't figure out what to do, and you think it is a reasonable thing to try, you can always post a question asking for assistance with the matter - essentially, how do I do this thing?

Comment: Please post the output of `grep swap /etc/sysctl.conf`

Comment: @terdon I get nothing in return. Not a single line

Comment: @Ufoguy sorry, I should have asked for `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness`. I am just checking if your machine is set up to make excessive use of swap.

Comment: @terdon It returns 60.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can cause this sort of problem is excessive use of [swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging). You can check your current value by running

```
 cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

In your case, you said that returns `60` which is a pretty high value. This means that your machine will be writing to swap instead of using RAM quite often. basically, if your RAM is ~60% full, it will start swapping (writing to disk) and this will greatly slow down your system. This is explained in more detail [here](http://rudd-o.com/linux-and-free-software/tales-from-responsivenessland-why-linux-feels-slow-and-how-to-fix-that) and you might want to read this [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness) post as well.

Anyway, since you have a fair amount of RAM, I suggest you reduce your `swappiness` to something less extreme like `10`. You can do this by issuing this command:

```
sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10
```

That should significantly improve the responsiveness of your system.